# Explain COUNT query with ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord, count

I want to do something like the following:

```
Post.count.explain # doesn't work
```

This fails because [EXPLAIN](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-explain/) is a method on Relation and `Post.count` isn't a relation. It's just a regular integer that is the result of the query. So how could a count query be EXPLAINed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a form that generates the exact same SQL query, but returns a Relation to call `explain` on:

```
Post.select('count(*)').explain
```

Both generate the SQL

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts`
```

...so the query plan should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

From [ActiveRecord::Relation#explain](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/00f7dbab7590c6ffd188da186067eb269e11580f/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L224), we can make that method accept a block.

```
module ExplainBlock
  def explain_block(&block)
    exec_explain(collecting_queries_for_explain { instance_exec(&block) })
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Relation.include(ExplainBlock)
```

Then `Post.all.explain_block { count }` .

Answer (score 0):

The COUNT shouldn't affect the query plan, since the only difference it does is to tell the database to fetch the row data, but the rows need to be found anyway with/without the COUNT.